# Github webhook is not created when creating a Google Cloud Build trigger

Tags: github, continuous-integration, webhooks, continuous-delivery, google-cloud-build

I have many projects which uses Google Cloud Build + Github build pipeline setup. However, there is this one project, which I cannot create a webhook in Github for.

It used to work - but commits to the repository doesn't trigger the build process any more. I deleted the trigger and added it again - but the webhook in Github is not created automatically for this project.

When I run the trigger manually, it picks the wrong, but fixed commit which I did before an year.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try delete a repository on Cloud Source Repositories and setup Google Cloud Build again ?

See:

- https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/running-builds/automate-builds

  > Note: For external repositories, such as GitHub and Bitbucket, you must have owner-level permissions for the Cloud Platform project with which you're working. When you set up a build trigger with an external repository for the first time, you'll need to set up authorization with that repository.
  >
  > After you've set up your external repository, Cloud Source Repository creates a mirror of your repository.
- https://source.cloud.google.com
- https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/deleting-a-repository
- https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository

Comment: This is what I'm going to try.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same issue. I can create a trigger for a repo, but I cannot connect the repo automatically to cloud build. We also have many projects, and this manual labor is sort of annoying.

Is there any (under the hood) github/gcloud api available in which I can connect a github repo to cloud build? I am aware that this can only be done by someone with admin privileges on a repo or organization in github.

After this, I will be able to run the command `gcloud build triggers create github [NAME]`